# How to make a plug and play ubuntu USB drive

Tags: boot, usb, system-settings, clone, community

Recently, I wanted to try to transfer an ubuntu system from VMware to my USB drive and achieve a plug and play result. There don't seem to be any tutorials online for this type of thing, or the tutorials require a new ubuntu system to be created on the usb drive. It's not like I'm throwing away files and data on my original Ubuntu system, is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Before copying files, you must...

- Partition and format the storage device
- `mount` that newly-created storage partition
- Set up the base system (`/proc`, `/sys`. `/dev`, `/run`)
- Install the bootloader

After copying files, you must...

- Reset your swapfile
- Update `/etc/fstab`, since your copied file will have the wrong UUIDs.

Folks who want to try this should read the [Debian documentation](https://www.debian.org/releases/stable/i386/apds03.en.html) on manually creating a system. You won't be using `debootstrap`, since you will be copying instead, but all the preparatory steps are similar.

This method takes longer, and is more error-prone, than the simpler and more common method of installing a new system and then copying only your data across.